# Why does assigning SQL source dynamically from a file via variable fail?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dynamic, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm moving data from Postgres to SQL Server.  In SSIS 2008 R2, I have a script task that reads from a text file and assigns the contents of the text file to a package variable.  This variable will be used to skirt the 4000 character expression limit in the source SQL definition because my SQL statement is very long.  When I check the value of the variable through `MsgBox`, I see that the variable is in fact populated from the flat file.

```
Public Sub Main()
    '
    Dim strFileName As String, strPathParent As String, strFullPath As String, SourceSQL As String
    Dim objFSO As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim SQLSourceVariable As String
    Const ForReading = 1

    objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strPathParent = "C:\Users\SourceSQL\"
    strFileName = "source.sql"
    strFullPath = strPathParent & strFileName

    objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFullPath, ForReading)
    SourceSQL = objFile.ReadAll.ToString()

    'MsgBox(SourceSQL)
    '
    Dts.Variables("User::SourceSQL").Value = SourceSQL

    objFile.Close()

    'MsgBox(Dts.Variables("User::SourceSQL").Value)

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

However, when I go into Expressions of the Data Flow Task and assign the supposedly populated variable `@[User::SourceSQL]` to the property `[ADO NET Source].[SqlCommand]` and run the package, I get a "medadata corrupted error" because the variable appears to be blank.  Basically, it's trying to shove blank variable as source into the data flow task and fails.

How can I have the variable be both populated in the script task and not populated when it gets to the data flow task?

Comment: Is it possible that you have the same variable at two different scopes?  i.e. that SourceSQL is both at a script task scope and at the package or data flow level?

Comment: Put a watch on the variable and use checkpoints to see what the value is at various stages of package execution.

Comment: Got my issue resolved by not forcing SQL from the Data Flow Task level via expression (which has the 4000 char limit), but instead pasting it into the source connection (which has a higher limit or no limit).  Whatever code I needed to change dynamically was added via Derived Column task.